# Should I store table's current page and sort order in React's state?

Tags: sorting, reactjs

I created a simple table that displays paginated data. Each new page or sorting change requires access to the backend and the database to get the filtered/sorted data, no handling is done on the frontend. After each data request, I update the state with the new content to display in the table, and that fires the react dom reconciliation.

Since it's the content refresh what fires the reconciliation, I am not sure whether the current page, sort field and sort direction should live on react's state or just use a variable in my class. I've successfully managed to do it both ways but I still don't know if the "thinner state" way is correct.

Comment: I think if you require the data to always be up to date - i.e. you want the data to resync when you paginate - you should just go with a variable. however, if the data doesn't have to be up to date, or if performance is a priority, or if data isn't updated often, you could store past fetched data and store the page/sort locally (in React state, as you say) and just merge new data into data you already have when you do eventually have to fetch (paginate beyond what you have stored).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heuristic I use when deciding between using state, and an internal class property goes something like this:

- *If its part of the public api*, where the values are passed in via a parent component or even passed down to children, **then use state**. e.g. `this.state.page`
- *But if its an internal implementation detail*, then **use a class property** following some sort convention. e.g. `this.__page`